# Ionic: EXIF data not complete

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, exif

I want to read the Date and Time when a Photo was taken from the `exif` data of a picture.

I use this library https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js to access `exif` and `$cordovaCamera` to get the picture.

The `$cordovaCamera` options: (I let the user decide where the picture should come from (gallery or camera) so `source` can be 1 or 0:

```
var options = {
    quality: 60, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: source,
    allowEdit: false,
    correctOrientation: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
 };
```

Getting the picture:

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
    cameraSuccess(imageData);
});
```

And processing it:

```
function cameraSuccess(imageURI) {

    var imageR = new Image();
    imageR.onload = function() {
        EXIF.getData(imageR, function() {
            alert(JSON.stringify(this));
        });
    };
    imageR.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageURI;

}
```

But this is the only `exif` data i get.

```
"exifdata":{  
  "Orientation":1,
  "ExifIFDPointer":38,
  "ColorSpace":1,
  "PixelXDimension":500,
  "PixelYDimension":375
},
"iptcdata":{  
}
```

I also tried `Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI` to make sure that `base64` is no problem.

I tested it on a ios-emulator (take image from gallery) with the above result and an android device (take image from camera) without any output.

Comment: I think instead of using exif external library you can use file plugin to get the details of file with date and time

Comment: Agree with @Anilkumar

Comment: Well i need other exif information as well, and i don't think that i can get those with the file plugin.

Answer (score 3):

With the following options I am currently able to POST to a server an image file containing the EXIF data (I am looking for date/time and GPS) from Android (5.1 Nexus 5). But not from iOS (8.4 iPhone 5).

```
    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    };
```

It seems that, in the Camera plugin process, iOS is somehow stripping most of the EXIF data: the ones remaining are similar to yours. By the way even setting

```
<preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="true"/>
```

in `config.xml` doesn't seem to help with GPS data.
In your case I suspect then that exif-js is trying to extract data no longer existing.

Still trying to find a solution, if I have any update I will post it.

Comment: I forgot: using targetWidth and targetHeight in the options was causing Android to strip the metadata as well, so maybe is the same for correctOrientation

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Cordova camera plugin which strips some tags when picking the image.